# If f is 0 at enough points, it is the 0 polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$, and let d be the largest $x_i$-degree of f for $0 \leq i \leq n$. Prove that f is the zero polynomial, if $f(a_1,...,a_n)=0$ for all points $(a_1,...,a_n) \in A^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ with $1\leq a_1 \leq d+1$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$.

I know how to prove that f is the 0 polynomial if it is 0 for all point in $\mathbb{Z}^n$. But here, we cannot use that it is an infinite field. So how would one go about proving this?

Comment: I studied a theorem if f(x_k)=0 for all k, where x_k is a sequence convergent to zero. Then, the function is identically 0.

Comment: sin x is zero for infinitely many points, but it is not the zero function.

Comment: @SwapnilTri $\mathbb{C}[x_1...x_n]$ denotes the ring of polynomials in $n$ variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Oh, i am so sorry.

Comment: Note that if you set any variable to $k$ for $k$ between 1 and $d+1$ you are in exactly the same situation with one fewer variable.  This suggests induction is a good way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Prove it by induction!
It's easy in one variable.
Then take $f(a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1},x_n)$: it is zero since it has $d+1$ zeros, so all the coefficients must be...

Comment: For the one variable case, do you have that f(a)=0 for infinitely many a, since $a \in A^n_{\mathbb{C}}$?

Comment: @math1234567 Sure, a **nonzero** polynomial of degree d has at most d zeros.